# R: Why is numeric data treated like non-numeric data?

Tags: dataframe, mean

my R script is:

```
aa <- data.frame("1","3","1.5","2.1")
mean(aa)
```

Then I get:

[1] NA

Warning message: In mean.default(aa) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Can this be solved without removing the quotation marks or changing `data.frame` to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `data.frame` if you want to get mean value for each column, you can do it using `colMeans` function:

```
aa <- data.frame("1","3","1.5","2.1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
aa <- sapply(aa, as.numeric)
colMeans(aa)
mean(colMeans(aa))  # if you want average across all columns
```

You must create the `data.frame` using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` otherwise all character values will be separate factors with ordinal `1` each. Numeric representation would be `1` for each value.

Comment: It should be a data.frame. I'm actually trying to reproduce an error.

Comment: I'd like to believe that `stringsAsFactors` is the thing you have trouble with.